# How should I approach rendering pixel grid in Pixi.js?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to make a simple, pixel based, realtime game to have fun with new HTML5 technologies:

- Web Sockets
- WebGL through Pixi.js

The concept of game is going to be something like Snake. To allow all kinds of patterns I decided to base the basic rendering on a pixel grid - this will also make it much easier to calculate collisions, I am not really do this to train my analytic geometry skills. Other visual effect will be added later, right now I just need to render pixels in several different colors.

What would be, in terms of performance, the best strategy? Modern screens are really large so I expect up to 5000 of individual pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems that dirty but easy way to do it is that we create some Graphics object from Pixi:

```
this.stage = new PIXI.Container();
...
this.gameMap = new PIXI.Graphics();
```

Then, within EVERY render operation where data has changed:

```
GameRenderer.prototype.drawPixels = function() {
  var gr = this.gameMap;
  this.stage.removeChild(this.gameMap);
  //This clears previous image. May be ommited in special cases
  gr.clear();

  for( y coordinate... ) {
    for( x coordinate...) {
      if(something here) {
        gr.lineStyle(0, 0x0000FF, 1);
        gr.beginFill(PIXEL COLOR HERE, 1);
        gr.drawRect(x+20, y+20, 1, 1);
      }
    }
    }
  }
  this.stage.addChild(this.gameMap);
}
```

Comment: This seems fine, but why remove and add the child every iteration? Just keep it in.

Comment: @DavidsKanal I honestly don't remember. I guess it maybe didn't update correctly without that? If you can confirm that it works without removing the child, I can change that in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it does work. Sorry to dig up such an old question :D